# Another Logic Problem

Tags: mathematics, pattern

If 
$$\begin{align}2*6&=7,\\4*2&=72\quad\text{and}\\7*3&=144\end{align}$$

then,

$$\;\;5*8=\;?\qquad\qquad$$

Comment: Is it relevant that 144 vf n ahzore va gur Svobanppv frdhrapr.

Comment: the others aren't so why would it matter if 144 is?  Just curious about your thinking...

Comment: what exactly...did @Mike Earnest just edit here that lends clarity and meaning to the initial post?  I didn't see any change.  Please explain.

Comment: @Drt I removed the [logical-deduction] tag and replaced it with [pattern], since this puzzle cannot be solved by logical inference alone.

Comment: if you used my answer to solve your homework assignment (https://puzzle.queryhome.com/16885/if-2-6-7-4-2-72-and-7-3-144-then-5-8) please consider accepting it

Comment: Your multiplication is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about any mathematic operation but can find this pattern(could be wrong!):

> $2∗6 = 7$;
> $4∗2 = 72$; 7 from RHS of 1st row and 2 1st number in 1st row.
> $7∗3 = 144$; 7*2 from RHS of 2nd row(multiply) and 4 1st number in 2nd row.

So,

> $5∗8 = 167$; $1*4*4$ from RHS of 3rd row and 7 1st number in 3rd row.

edit: just noticed i mistaken 7 with 17, so corrected;)

Answer (score 0):

I found the same pattern as @Preet, but had a different result:

> $2 * 6 = 7 \Rightarrow 7 $; initial statement
>  $4 * 2 = 72 \Rightarrow 7$ ~ $2 $; product of previous result (just 7) & first row (2)
>  $7 * 3 = 144 \Rightarrow 14$ ~ $4 $; product of previous result  $(7*2 = 14)$ and first row (4)
>  $5 * 8 = 567 \Rightarrow 56$ ~ $7 $; product of previous result  $(14*4 = 56)$ and first row (7)

So the answer might be

> $567.$

Answer (score -5):

> Strip out the symbols and multiply by 16 to find the next row
>  
>  
>    2*6=7 =>   267 * 16 =   4272
>  
>   4*2=72 =>  4272 * 16 =  73144
>  
>  7*3=144 => 73144 * 16 = 58**1704**
>  
>  therefore: 5*8=**1704**

Comment: $4272\cdot16=68352$ and $73144\cdot16=1170304$? Or just note that the products of the units digits don't even match? Or that $581703$ is odd?

Comment: edited to correct

Comment: How are you obtaining these numbers?

Comment: Yes, I agree with @noedne, the second and third products aren't correct.